# Rstudio Automatically use input file name in read.csv when using write.csv & two headers

Tags: r, file

Currently I use a script to edit columns of a dataset.
I click run on Rmarkdown, and my first line of code is

```
Data <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep = "," ,header = T , skip = 2)
```

This skips the first 2 lines and gives the third line a header for the file that I select after clicking run. When the script finishes, the last line of code is

```
write.csv(Data, "FileName.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

This removes all the row names that were given numerical values on the left, and saving a FileName.csv in my working directory.

My question is if I do a read.csv of a certain file that I pick, for example, the file name is "FileName.csv", is there a way to use that name that I picked the same name as the file that I use

```
write.csv
```

and it would give out the name FileName on my working directory without manually writing it. Also is there a way to add back the other first 2 lines that I skipped when doing write.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the filename from file.choose and save the skipped lines to write out later.

```
## Capture file name
FileName = file.choose()

# Capture skipped header lines
IN=file(FileName, open="r")
Header=readLines(IN, 2)
Input <- read.csv(IN)          # No need to skip lines now
close(IN)

## Whatever processing

## Output
OUT = file(FileName ,open="w")
writeLines(Header, OUT)
write.csv(Input, OUT,  row.names=FALSE)
close(OUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the filepath/filename into a variable and use that variable in both read.csv and write.csv:

```
myfile <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(file=myfile, ...)
   ... lots of code...
write.csv(data, file=myfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment if I could as I am not sure this is a full answer, but I guess you could just use:

```
Data <- read.csv(file.choose(), skip=2))
FileName <- basename(file.choose())
write.csv(Data, FileName, row.names=FALSE)
```